# Eager Loading in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I'm new in laravel. I want to ask for example I have report_type model and also report model which is one to many relationship.  I want to show the report_types and also the reports too. What is the best practice for this one? Should I use report.report_type only or I also have to add report in eager loading.

```
$report_histories = Report_history::where('report_id', $report->id)->with(['employee', 'report', 'report.report_type'])->get();
```

Comment: You have to write each thing you want to eager load, so if you want to eager load report and also report_type, you have to write both as you did.

Answer (score 0):

```
$report_histories = Report_history::with('report.report_type','employee')
                                    ->where('report_id', $report->id)
                                    ->get();
```